# knockout.js and observableArray not updating DOM upon second click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I've looked at a lot of the previous answers, and tried several things, but nothing I do allows me to update my DOM the second time I try to applyBindings.

Take a look at the following fiddle which demonstrates the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/rARfx/4/

While I'm pulling the data via $.getJSON() IRL, the fiddle still reproduces the problem with the inline JSON I fiddled and the code that's there.

Things I have tried are commented out (will/hasMutated, replace, removeAll).

What I'm hoping to accomplish is that my element of five news items for figure X (Usher) would be updated/replaced with five news items for figure Y (Lohan), but it'd be a sign of progress if I could even get elements 5-9 appended to 0-4 and see 10 li tags.

To reproduce the problem, run the fiddle, then click the "Do It Again" link to simulate a JSON load and note that instead of showing the new data elements, it just produces a blank ul tag with no children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't the same object bound to multiple models. Instead, simply update the model with the new information and the changes will be reflected in the view.

I've changed the code to do exactly that: http://jsfiddle.net/rARfx/5/

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Looks like I have a few more things to learn about knockout.